# How to draw and fill the width region of the disk in Inkscape?

Tags: inkscape, drawing, diagram

How to draw and fill the shaded region of the disk in Inkscape as shown in the image below?
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Draw an ellipse, and duplicate it using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd>
2. Move it above the lower one (you can nudge it with the up arrow key on your keyboard)
3. With snapping enabled, draw a rectangle to intersect with the two ellipses (see example below)
4. With the select tool <kbd>S</kbd> hold down <kbd>Shift</kbd> and also select the bottom ellipse
5. Do *Path > Union* or use the shortcut <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>+</kbd>, and set the fill to grey
6. Select the top ellipse and set the fill to white

Example showing steps 3 to 6

[image]